# javascript variable changes to null on addEventListener

Tags: variables, inheritance, null, prototype

I have a function named `process`, when I put a breakpoint inside that function and scroll the page then the variables `target` and `elnode`, at the top of the script, turns into null while others keep their values.

I am new to prototype stuff and inheritance so it's a bit confusing.
When you look at the `scrollDirection()` function `this.node` is still there  when I call it with `scrollDirection.call(this);` (at function process).

https://plnkr.co/7lgIn6ggugltqUsvHrzv

Comment: Neither `target` nor `elnode` turn into null when I run it.

Comment: All of those variables are accessible everywhere inside the `scrollSpy` function.